# How to get Input range to show first value on page load, and estimated slider value?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I developed a jQuery sip calculator. Calculator is working fine. But I want it to show value 2000 and its estimated calculated value on page load. Can anyone help me to get it? Below is my jQuery code.

```js
< script src = "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" > < /script> <
  script src = "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" > < /script> <
  script src = "https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" > < /script> <
  script >
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#slider").change(function() {
      max: 16000;
      value: 2000;

      var investment = $('#slider').val();
      var annualRate = 17;
      var monthlyRate = annualRate / 12 / 100; //Rate of interest
      var years = $('#select').val();;
      var months = years * 12; //Time period 
      var futureValue = 0; //Final Value
      $('#slider_value').html(investment);
      futureValue = investment * (Math.pow(1 + monthlyRate, months) - 1) / monthlyRate;

      $('#futur_value1').html(futureValue);

      document.getElementById('futur_value1').innerHTML = futureValue.toLocaleString('en-IN', {
        maximumFractionDigits: 2,
        style: 'currency',
        currency: 'INR'
      });
    });
  }); <
/script>
```

```html
<div class="sip">
  <div>
    <h2 id="slider_value" class="text-warning"></h2>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group"><input id="slider" class="form-control" max="16000" min="2000" step="500" type="range" value="2000" /></div>
  <div class="select">No. of years
    <select id="select" class="form-control">
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="5">5</option>
      <option value="10">10</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="est-vl">Estimated Value</div>
    <h1 id="futur_value1" class="text-success"></h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pour your logic in a separate function and call it when your document is ready

```js
function sliderCalculate() {
  max: 16000;
  value: 2000;

  var investment = $('#slider').val();
  var annualRate = 17;
  var monthlyRate = annualRate / 12 / 100; //Rate of interest
  var years = $('#select').val();;
  var months = years * 12; //Time period 
  var futureValue = 0; //Final Value
  $('#slider_value').html(investment);
  futureValue = investment * (Math.pow(1 + monthlyRate, months) - 1) / monthlyRate;

  $('#futur_value1').html(futureValue);

  document.getElementById('futur_value1').innerHTML = futureValue.toLocaleString('en-IN', {
    maximumFractionDigits: 2,
    style: 'currency',
    currency: 'INR'
  });
}
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#slider").change(sliderCalculate);
  $("#select").change(sliderCalculate);
  sliderCalculate()
});
```

```html
<div class="sip">
  <div>
    <h2 id="slider_value" class="text-warning"></h2>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group"><input id="slider" class="form-control" max="16000" min="2000" step="500" type="range" value="2000" /></div>
  <div class="select">No. of years
    <select id="select" class="form-control">
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="5">5</option>
      <option value="10">10</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="est-vl">Estimated Value</div>
    <h1 id="futur_value1" class="text-success"></h1>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks man. You are a savior. Can you please help me in  one thing more?  I also want to get estimated value on selected year from dropdown

Comment: No Problem :) But validate the answer who solved your issue and up vote any useful answer. because tht's another issue

Comment: I edited the answer you just need to add a change listener on  `$("#select")`